# multiple port-forwarding, client-linux box-server

Tags: linux, soap, portforwarding

I've installed soap-ui software on my laptop [A] [ip: 172.30.X.X] and I'm trying to connect to a Webservice which is provided on a server [C] [ip: 10.10.X.X]. the problem is that I dont have a direct access/permission to connect directly to that server. however there is a Linux box in the network [B] [ip: 172.43.X.X] which has access to that server and it is also accessible from my laptop.

So, actually I'm looking for a way to redirect to my soap request to the server [C] by using the linux box [B]

A -> B -> C

My first try was to setup iptables on [B], but with no luck:
    iptables -t nat -A  PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.43.X.X --dport 9003 -j DNAT --to 10.10.X.X:8088

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know is to use [SSH Port Forwarding](http://support.ssh.com/manuals/server-admin/32/Port_Forwarding.html), per the linked manual page -

> Port forwarding, or tunneling, is a way to forward otherwise insecure TCP traffic through SSH Secure Shell.
>
> ...
>
> For example, if you issue the command
>
> ```
> ssh2 -L 1234:localhost:23 username@host
> ```
>
> all traffic coming to port 1234 on the client will be forwarded to port 23 on the server (host). Note that localhost will be resolved by the sshdserver after the connection is established. In this case localhost therefore refers to the server (host) itself.